# ng Commands are not working they ask for How Do you want to open the file

Tags: node.js, angular

Here i added some screenshots of problem , what i get after ng command.[Image appears is after ng command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coiE3.png)

and when i select any of them then it displays ng file.[Image for after clicking one option from list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAAAf.png)

Comment: In the right bottom where you see powershell, use the 'v' (dropdown) button to choose command prompt then use ng commands

Comment: Thank You Ashish Dahiya. It works for me .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.